Find a sequence function for combinatorial sequences
I´m trying to find a sequence function for the following sequence:
$0, 1, 85, 419, 973, 1747, 2741, 3955, 5389, 7043, 8917, 11011, 13325, 15859, 18613, 21587, 24781, 28195$
The first term is generated from a parameter $n=1$, the second from $n=2$, and so on.
When using the Wolfram´s function FindSequenceFunction[], it doesn´t provide any useful result. However, if I remove the first 2 terms $0,1$, it returns the sequence function $f(n)=110 n^2+4 n-29$. Since it misses the first two terms, I evaluate $f(n-2)$ to get the actual corrected result, which equals to $110 n^2-436 n+403$.
The problem is that the resulting $f(n-2)$ function equals $77$ instead of $0$ when $n=1$, and when $n=2$, it returns $-29$ instead of $1$. I wonder if there exists any transformation I can apply to the $f(n-2)$ function so that it returns the correct result for $n=1$ and $n=2$, considering all the current outputs for $n>2$ as correct.
Also, I tried similar sequences (created from the 2. case of this question, which counts arrangements of clusters with $k$ kings on a $n\times n$ chessboard), for example:
The sequence from this question counts $4$ king clusters, but for $k<4$:
$(k=2)=>0, 6, 20, 42, 72, 110, 156, 210, 272$
$(k=3)=>0, 4, 48, 132, 256, 420, 624, 868, 1152, 1476$
Returning the correct generating functions:
$(k=2)=>4 n^2-6 n+2$
$(k=3)=>20 n^2-56 n+36$
As you can see, for 2 and 3 values of $k$ Wolfram finds a sequence function with the initial values $0,6$ and $0,4$ in it. So, I also wonder if there exists a way of proving if a sequence function for higher values of $k$ can exist or not depending on the result Wolfram returns when using the first $0,\cdots$ initial values inside FindSequenceFunction[].

You are using the wrong term, "generating function" is not what you are looking for. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Definitions. I believe you are looking for an interpolation polynomial.

If the function $f(n)$ is created by not including $0$ and $1$, there are very few chances that $0$ and $1$ will be in its image. Let's say you had the first two terms being $77777777$ and $10101010101$, then the function Wolfram provided would be the same (since it ignores the first two terms) but as you can see it's pretty unlikely to hit them, so shifting the index won't help you.

@zima I tried interpolation, when $k=2$ and $k=3$ it provides the correct solution. But for $k=4$ or more it doesn´t find anything useful unless I remove the first 2 terms. That´s why I added at the end of the question if there is any proof that these initial terms define the existence of such polynomials.

@zima Also, for $k=5$ I have to remove more than 2 terms for it to exist. In this case, I would need to correct more values of its image.

The function guessgf in Maple's gfun package produces an ordinary generating function $$\frac{30 x^{4}-167 x^{3}-82 x^{2}-x}{\left(x -1\right)^{3}}$$ which has the Maclaurin series
$$ 30 x - 77 + \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(110 n^2 - 216 n + 77\right) x^n$$
Thus your sequence would be $$f(n) = 110 n^2 - 216 n + 77 - 77 \delta_{0n} + 30 \delta_{1n}$$ where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker delta.

Given by Mathematica, the sequence is
$$a_{n}=\frac{30 (n-3)\, a_{n-1} +\left(18370 n^2-82832 n+92261\right)}{30 n+17}\qquad \text{with} \qquad a_1=0$$.

What function did you use to obtain a recurrence from the sequence elements?

@Cardstdani  FindSequenceFunction[%]  $\large\text{!!}$

The recurrence seems to miss a general solution. At least with the initial terms included in the sequence. Is there any proof for that?
